# jQuery Uncaught TypeError with Theme Punch Revolution Slider

Tags: jquery

I'm having a problem that I can't track down. I'm using the [Revolution Slider](http://themes.themepunch.com/?theme=revolution_jq) and I keep on getting jQuery errors:

```
 ▼ Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (repeated 86 times)

    p.extend.each                            jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2  
    a.fn.cssAnimationRemove     jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js:18  
    (anonymous function)        jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js:18
```

The problem is on [this page](http://coolcoops.com/home) and I believe it's causing the weird problem where the picture doesn't fully disappear when the slides change. It leaves the picture there, and then it suddenly disappears. Like this:

[image]

It's given me nothing but trouble and I can't seem to track it down. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does that library have a non-minified version available?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy One of the JS files does.

Comment: Try using that file, it will give you a more readable error.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy okay, now I have a line number for the themepunch file: `a.fn.cssAnimationRemove: jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js:296` and `(anonymous function) jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js:383`

Comment: https://github.com/VPenkov/okayNav/issues/21#issuecomment-356888135

Answer (score 3):

After prettifying `jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js` and stepping through using Chrome's web inspector, I was able to track down the cause of the issue.

It is being used by a call to [jquery's each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function on an undefined object.

I wouldn't recommend fixing or altering code that you don't own, but for now you can fix the bug by just putting in an undefined check on the cssAnimationRemove function:

Prettified, the original function looks like this:

```
a.fn.cssAnimationRemove = function () {
    var b = this;
    var c = b.data("cssAnimations");
    var d = b.data("identity");
    a.each(c, function(a, b) {
        c[a] = b.splice(d + 1, 1);
    });
    b.data("cssAnimations", c);
};
```

The modified prettified version just needs an undefined check inserted. It will look something like this:

```
a.fn.cssAnimationRemove = function () {
    var b = this;
    var c = b.data("cssAnimations");
    var d = b.data("identity");
    if (typeof c !== "undefined") {
        a.each(c, function(a, b) {
            c[a] = b.splice(d + 1, 1);
        });
    }
    b.data("cssAnimations", c);
};
```

We came across the same issue after buying a theme that includes this version of the slider (which I suspect is an older version, as the files on the Revolution Slider website are not the same as the files we have locally).

Comment: Sweet! I'll have to make those changes and come back and accept it! Thanks soo much!! I just gave up so I'm glad you figured it out. :D