# Hi i have wordpress revolution slider errors Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'is_mobile' of undefined

Tags: revolution-slider

JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1

```
revolution.extension.actions.min.js?ver=5.3.1.5:7 
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'is_mobile' of undefined
```

Does anybody know what this issue could be? It is slowing down my site and I would like to fox it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Realy? a have to go first to learn how i can make a good question? i'm not a noob, this is my question i have a error in slider revolition and i show it above so i dont know what i do wrong? i think my question is good. this error above what i get so i dont know how i ask the question good. and sorry for me bad english. i thing more people have this issue.

Comment: Yes, you have to learn how to write questions on Stackoverflow. There are guidelines which you must follow and you have to make sure it's a valid question for this site. Your question is about debugging and this is what is expected for such questions: _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]"_.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Uncaught TypeError with Theme Punch Revolution Slider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046693/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-with-theme-punch-revolution-slider)

Answer (score 11):

For anyone else seeing this bug, make sure "Defer Javascript Loading" under `WP Admin -> Slider Revolution -> Global Settings` is **off**

It's occurring because only the main slider revolution JS file loading is deferred, the plugins are not (at least not on 5.4.1), and the plugins were erroring from trying to access `jQuery.fn.revolution.is_mobile` when `jQuery.fn.revolution` hasn't been set yet

Comment: after defer javascript loading off in global settings will showing revolution slider error

Answer (score 1):

For me this problem is related to W3TC plugin, it happens when I minify the js files and if I uncheck minification of js, no more error is there.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to link 2 additional JavaScript files:

```
<!-- REVOLUTION JS FILES -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>
```